# AWS CodeDeploy agent not installing on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, devops, aws-code-deploy

I tried installing codedeploy agent on `ubuntu 22.04` but not working. I have installed `ruby 2.6.0` via rbenv.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-7:~$ sudo ./install --sanity-check  deb
I, [2022-08-10T06:26:28.905059 #47961]  INFO -- : Starting Ruby version check.
I, [2022-08-10T06:26:28.905394 #47961]  INFO -- : Starting update check.
I, [2022-08-10T06:26:28.905593 #47961]  INFO -- : Checking AWS_REGION environment variable for region information...
I, [2022-08-10T06:26:28.905770 #47961]  INFO -- : Checking EC2 metadata service for region information...
I, [2022-08-10T06:26:28.921018 #47961]  INFO -- : Checking AWS_DOMAIN environment variable for domain information...
I, [2022-08-10T06:26:28.921228 #47961]  INFO -- : Checking EC2 metadata service for domain information...
I, [2022-08-10T06:26:28.926802 #47961]  INFO -- : Downloading version file from bucket aws-codedeploy-ap-south-1 and key latest/LATEST_VERSION...
I, [2022-08-10T06:26:28.927009 #47961]  INFO -- : Endpoint: https://aws-codedeploy-ap-south-1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/latest/LATEST_VERSION
I, [2022-08-10T06:26:28.966467 #47961]  INFO -- : Running version 1.3.2-1902
I, [2022-08-10T06:26:28.966733 #47961]  INFO -- : Running version matches target version, skipping install
I, [2022-08-10T06:26:28.966856 #47961]  INFO -- : Update check complete.
I, [2022-08-10T06:26:28.966972 #47961]  INFO -- : Stopping updater.
```

I have also tried to install the .deb file manually but not working

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-7:~$ sudo dpkg -i codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_all.deb 
(Reading database ... 75862 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_all.deb ...
Failed to stop codedeploy-agent.service: Unit codedeploy-agent.service not loaded.
Unable to stop the running codedeploy-agent
Canceling upgrade.
dpkg: error processing archive codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_all.deb (--install):
 new codedeploy-agent package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_all.deb
```

Comment: It's not supported yet.  See [Operating systems supported by the CodeDeploy agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent.html#codedeploy-agent-supported-operating-systems)

Comment: It is a shame that Ubuntu 22.04 is not supported yet

Answer (score 37):

Run the following commands in order:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full ruby-webrick wget -y

cd /tmp

wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/releases/codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_all.deb

mkdir codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_ubuntu22

dpkg-deb -R codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_all.deb codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_ubuntu22

sed 's/Depends:.*/Depends:ruby3.0/' -i ./codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_ubuntu22/DEBIAN/control

dpkg-deb -b codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_ubuntu22/

sudo dpkg -i codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_ubuntu22.deb

sudo systemctl list-units --type=service | grep codedeploy

sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

Comment: I had same problem in Ubuntu 22.04, your solution was awesome and solved my problem completely. thanks :)

Comment: This should be added to the official aws code deploy documentation lol. It suggests you use apt install ruby-full, but then fails because the installed version of ruby is invalid. I'm assuming that sed command you have bypasses that, hopefully no side-effects... but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install the latest version of the CodeDeploy Agent and are ok with also installing JQ you can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This installs the CodeDeploy agent and its prerequisites on Ubuntu 22.04.

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jq ruby-full ruby-webrick wget -y

SOURCE="https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/releases/"
DEBFILE=$(curl -s https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/LATEST_VERSION| jq .deb -r| sed -e 's|releases/||')
DEBNAME=$(echo $DEBFILE | sed -e 's|.deb||')

cd /tmp
wget $SOURCE$DEBFILE
mkdir $DEBNAME
dpkg-deb -R $DEBFILE $DEBNAME
sed 's/Depends:.*/Depends:ruby3.0/' -i ./$DEBNAME/DEBIAN/control
dpkg-deb -b $DEBNAME/
sudo dpkg -i $DEBFILE
systemctl list-units --type=service | grep codedeploy
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```